# Sending money to a correct IBAN but a non existing swift code, shall the transaction be processed?

Tags: germany, swift, iban, egypt

I made an international transaction from my bank account in EGYPT to my German blocked account in Germany and while doing the bank transfer I entered my IBAN and it was a correct one, while I had to choose the bank name from a Checklist, I had no option to write the swift code myself so I searched for the bank and it matches the name and address however the swift code was different from the swift code I had in the last letter (it was supposed to be ‘B’ and but in the checklist it was ‘1’ and then I made the transaction and then found that the swift code that was provided in the checklist was a non existing one, shall the transaction be processed or what shall happen?

Comment: There is a good chance the transaction will be processed just fine.